# Groovy JSON manipulation: How to replace dot notation with nested JSON structure?

Tags: java, groovy

I want to convert the "."  to a nested JSON block structure inside a JSON block in Groovy. I already go through all the things that are posted on this platform but have not found any suitable way. so please suggest anyway.

Actual:

```
[{"sender.senderContactInformation.senderContactPrefix": "Mr.","sender.senderContactInformation.senderContactMiddleInitial": "man","ord.ordToAddr1": "US","dummy-target": "dummydefault","sender.senderContactInformation.SenderContactType": "","senderIdentifierName": "Abcxyz","orderLineItems": [{"orderLineItemActionCode": "78","OrderLineItemQuantity": "1","patientID": "CKIO090","defender.defenderContactInformation": "","orderLineItemDetails": [{"orderLineItemDetailCode": "1","ds1.dsType.dsName": ""}]}]}]
```

Desired:

```
[{"sender": {"senderContactInformation": {"senderContactPrefix": "Mr.","senderContactMiddleInitial": "man","SenderContactType": ""}},"ord": {"ordToAddr1": "US"},"dummy-target": "dummydefault","senderIdentifierName": "Abcxyz","orderLineItems": [{"orderLineItemActionCode": "78","OrderLineItemQuantity": "1","patientID": "CKIO090","defender": {"defenderContactInformation": ""},"orderLineItemDetails": [{"orderLineItemDetailCode": "1","ds1": {"dsType": {"dsName": ""}}}]}]}]
```

Comment: Please add the code you have tried and how it failed (e.g. errors,
stacktraces, logs, ...) so we can improve on it.

Comment: https://groovy-lang.org/processing-json.html

Answer (score 0):

Use `JsonSlurper` to parse `Json` and replace the dot notation with a nested JSON structure in Groovy as below-

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper

def json = '[{"sender.senderContactInformation.senderContactPrefix": "Mr.","sender.senderContactInformation.senderContactMiddleInitial": "man","ord.ordToAddr1": "US","dummy-target": "dummydefault","sender.senderContactInformation.SenderContactType": "","senderIdentifierName": "Abcxyz","orderLineItems": [{"orderLineItemActionCode": "78","OrderLineItemQuantity": "1","patientID": "CKIO090","defender.defenderContactInformation": "","orderLineItemDetails": [{"orderLineItemDetailCode": "1","ds1.dsType.dsName": ""}]}]}]'

def parsedJson = new JsonSlurper().parseText(json)

def replaceDotNotation(jsonObj) {
    jsonObj.collectEntries { key, value ->
        def newKey = key.replace('.', '-')
        [newKey, value instanceof Map ? replaceDotNotation(value) : value]
    }
}

def transformedJson = replaceDotNotation(parsedJson)

def resultJson = new groovy.json.JsonBuilder(transformedJson).toPrettyString()
println resultJson
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way that uses recursion. I'm no psychic, but in case you need the inverse I've added a second method...

```java
String jsonWithDots = """[{"sender.senderContactInformation.senderContactPrefix": "Mr.","sender.senderContactInformation.senderContactMiddleInitial": "man","ord.ordToAddr1": "US","dummy-target": "dummydefault","sender.senderContactInformation.SenderContactType": "","senderIdentifierName": "Abcxyz","orderLineItems": [{"orderLineItemActionCode": "78","OrderLineItemQuantity": "1","patientID": "CKIO090","defender.defenderContactInformation": "","orderLineItemDetails": [{"orderLineItemDetailCode": "1","ds1.dsType.dsName": ""}]}]}]"""
String jsonWithoutDots = """[{"sender": {"senderContactInformation": {"senderContactPrefix": "Mr.","senderContactMiddleInitial": "man","SenderContactType": ""}},"ord": {"ordToAddr1": "US"},"dummy-target": "dummydefault","senderIdentifierName": "Abcxyz","orderLineItems": [{"orderLineItemActionCode": "78","OrderLineItemQuantity": "1","patientID": "CKIO090","defender": {"defenderContactInformation": ""},"orderLineItemDetails": [{"orderLineItemDetailCode": "1","ds1": {"dsType": {"dsName": ""}}}]}]}]"""

def withDots = new JsonSlurper().parseText(jsonWithDots)
assert inverseDotNotation(withDots) == new JsonSlurper().parseText(jsonWithoutDots)
assert transformToDotNotation(inverseDotNotation(withDots)) == new JsonSlurper().parseText(jsonWithDots)

def inverseDotNotation(object) {
    switch (object) {
        case List:
            return object.collect { inverseDotNotation(it) }
        case Map:
            Map map = [:]
            object.each { k, v ->
                List keys = k.split(/\./).toList()
                def lastKey = keys.removeLast()
                keys.inject(map) { acc, val ->
                    if (!(acc.containsKey(val))) {
                        acc."$val" = [:]
                    }
                    acc."$val"
                }."$lastKey" = inverseDotNotation(v)
            }
            return map
        default:
            return object
    }
}

def transformToDotNotation(object, String key=""){
    switch(object){
        case Map:
            return object.collectEntries { k, v -> transformToDotNotation(v, !key ? k : key + "." + k) }
        case List:
            return key
                    ? [(key): object.collect { v -> transformToDotNotation(v) }]
                    : object.collect { v -> transformToDotNotation(v) }
        default:
            return key ? [(key): object] : object
    }
}
```